# How can I provide language specific access to Multi-lingual Associations?

Tags: joomla-3.x, multilingual, joomla-3.7, translation

I'm trying to get away from the deprecated Josetta translation component, which has always served us well, but is choking on php 7. I like what I see in 3.7 with the ability to perform side-by-side translations. I am trying to provide access to the interface in a way that any given user can only access the English version and their particular language. I've been trying some trial and error, but I'm not making much progress. I'm hoping there are others who have attempted this who might provide some guidance. Ideally, the English version would be read only, but I can live with the translators having access to it if necessary. I would also prefer that they do their editing on the front-end, if possible.

Comment: Have you tried adding the articles in different categories (EN, DE...) and give the corresponding users access to only those categories?